# My dynamically created widgets are not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-activity

My code compiles fine, and when I start the Activity, its associated layout is displayed, but the 
widgets I dynamically create thereafter in the onCreate() do not display.

Why wouldn't they?

Eclipse doesn't drop into the Debug Perspective, they simply don't show up.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class Authorize_Activity_DynamicControls extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize);

        LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this); 
        llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        llp.weight = 1.0f; 

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext()); 
        cb.setText("1"); 
        cb.setLayoutParams(llp); 
        llay.addView(cb);

        ScrollView svh = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHost);
        svh.addView(llay);
    }
```

...and here's the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/demand"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/space"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/contact"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewHost"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might need to invalidate the whole view manually to get the desired result, so try adding this line to the end:

```
svh.invalidate();
```

Comment: Adding the invalidate() didn't help, but I reckon it doesn't harm anything, either, so for now it sits there.

Comment: Can you try something? Can you remove the child LinearLayout section in the xml file (so that the ScrollView is the only child of the base LinearLayout) and check if you can see the ScrollView along with the LinearLayout you had added to it dynamically?

Comment: OK, thanks, Soham, that helps - the dynamically added widgets now display. But the dynamically added widgets display in the same "row" as the widgets declared in the xml, and I need them to be on their own "row", below those widgets declared in xml. How do I force that to happen?

Comment: I updated the xml above to reflect what it is now, after incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: Got you, can you change the android:layout_width="wrap_content" attribute to android:layout_width="fill_parent" for each widget in the xml? so that each <TextView ..> or <ScrollView ..> occupies the whole width of the parent

Comment: also change android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to invalidate the views you've added in onCreate().  Without having the XML layout file it's also some guesswork to try to answer the post confidently.  Have you tried using a TextView instead of checkbox?

Comment: I've added the layout file to my original post; it renders just fine - it's the dynamically added stuff that fails to display.